# html helper dropdown list to display hardcoded values in my view, not values from database

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I want to be able to display a dropdownlist that has values not from my database, but have hardcoded values that will be used to perform an insert query later. How would I go about doing it?

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("Chart Type", "Horizontal") %>
```

I need values Horizontal, Vertical, Pie to be in the dropdownlist.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("Chart Type", new List<SelectListItem>
                     {
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Horizontal", Value = "Horizontal" }, 
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Vertical", Value = "Vertical" },
                        new SelectListItem{ Text="Pie", Value = "Pie" }
                     }) %>
```